# How do I make a SKSpritenode move to the touch location in swift SpriteKit

Tags: swift

Hi I am making a game where a node should move to the touch location and I have asked before and it is still not working. Here is my code, hopefully you can help me. I have a file called Player.swift with this code inside it:

```
import SpriteKit
class Player: SKSpriteNode {
let playerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "head")

init() {
    super.init(texture: playerTexture, color: .clear, size: playerTexture.size())
}

// Satisfy the NSCoder required init.
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}}
```

and then I have the gamescene.swift file with this inside of it:

```
import SpriteKit
class GameScene: SKScene {
let player = Player()
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    addChild(player)
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        player.position = touch.location(in: self)
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your touch event is registered? Just put a print("moved") in the touches moves function to be sure.